# Poisson distribution on uniform distribution

Tags: probability, independence, variance, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

The number of emails I receive at work per hour has Poisson distribution: $X \text{~} Po(4)$.

Tomorrow I will work for T hours, where T is uniformly distributed on {$2,3,4,5$} - with number of hours worked independent of number of emails received.

Find the variance of the total number of emails received tomorrow.

Would I find a way to calculate the joint distribution, then find the variance of that distribution? Or is there a formula for applying the uniform distribution on poisson that I am unaware of?

Comment: You mean the variance of the total numbers of email received instead of phone calls right?

Comment: Yep sorry, will edit

Comment: To find the variance of $Z$ it suffices to find $E[Z]$ and $E[Z^2]$. You can find the distribution of $Z$ if you want but often it is not necessary. The only formula needed for this problem is the law of total expectation, which means you just condition on the 4 possible situations that can arise.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of finding it on the interval $[2,5]$ for some reason. Much easier question now.

Answer (score 0):

By the law of total expectation:
$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(Y|2)\mathbb{P}(T=2) + \mathbb{E}(Y|3)\mathbb{P}(T=3) + \mathbb{E}(Y|4)\mathbb{P}(T=4) + \mathbb{E}(Y|5)\mathbb{P}(T=5)$

$= \mathbb{E}(X \text{~} Po(8))*1/4 + \mathbb{E}(X \text{~} Po(12))*1/4 + \mathbb{E}(X \text{~} Po(16))*1/4 + \mathbb{E}(X \text{~} Po(20))*1/4$

$=\frac{8}{4} + \frac{12}{4} +\frac{16}{4} +\frac{20}{4} = 14 $

Similarly,

$\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(Y^2|2)\mathbb{P}(T=2) + \mathbb{E}(Y^2|3)\mathbb{P}(T=3) + \mathbb{E}(Y^2|4)\mathbb{P}(T=4) + \mathbb{E}(Y^2|5)\mathbb{P}(T=5)$

Since $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \lambda^2 + \lambda$ for Poisson distribution, we have:

$\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=230$

Therefore, $Var(Y) = 230 - 14^2 = 34$